# GAE memcache lifetime is very low

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, lifetime

acoording to documentation memcache unit can have a max lifetime of one month unless it is deleted due to servers ram capacity problems.

my app stores {'customer_id':'customer_name'} in memcache (1600+ items), which is used for autocomplete and customer index needs.

heres the code:

```
memcache.add('keys', keys, time=86400) #if 'keys' is absent, then all memcache items are regenerated.
memcache.add_multi(names, time=86500, key_prefix='customer_id_')
```

The problem is that most of my entries expire in an hour or so, leaving only 10 or 11 items. docs also say that if time is not set, the default life time of memcache item is one hour.

So did i set life cycle of memcache incorectly (if so, why does it leave 10 items) or is google memcache this unreliable for 11+ items (what should i do in this case? store this data in XML somehow?)?

Comment: 86400 seconds is only one day, so they won't last any longer than that in any case.

Comment: I meant them to be one day. google quotas reset every 24h ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current stats for my quiet app show it can easily hold hundreds of items for several hours:

```
Item count:         285 item(s)
Total cache size:   5462609 byte(s)
Oldest item age:    11 hour(s) 38 min(s) 29 second(s)
```

If you have 1600 items and one item (key+data) size is less than 500 bytes, I'd recommend to store them all in one single memcache entry as a dictionary or something.

Comment: my stats show that I lost 1400+ items since they were generated 7 minutes ago. are you using a subscription?

also, adding dict() as a memcache value was my 1st idea(ok, it was second, 1st was to add a db range, but that turned out to be >1MB), but it threw some (pickle?) errors. So i thought it cant be done. After trying to google 'why' to argue with you, i tried it on smaller amount of data and it worked... :S gonna test on all records now.

Comment: hmm... now adding the whole 1600 item dic() as one memcache item works fine. Must have been doing something wrong last time. Thanks!